# Split a string into 3 columns - with a twist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a very long text string being imported into a table.  I would like to split the string up; I have a routine to pull the data into a table, but it creates all the data in a single field in a table.

Example Text:

```
05/10/2018 21:14,#FXAAF00123456,,Cup 1 X Plane,0.00000,OK,Cup 1 Y Plane,0.00000,OK,Cup 1 Z Plane,40.64252,OK,Cup 2 X Plane,77.89434,OK,..etc
```

(The test string is much longer than this, in the region of 1500-1700 characters, but with the same structure in the rest of the string).

This data is a series of test measurements, with the name of the value, the value, and the OK/NOK indicator.

I want the results to be stored in a table (variable) with three fields, so the data above becomes:

```
Field1|Field2|Field3
05/10/2018 21:14|#FXAAF00123456|null|
Cup 1 X Plane|0.00000|OK|
Cup 1 Y Plane|0.00000|OK|
Cup 1 Z Plane|40.64252|OK|
Cup 2 X Plane|77.89434|OK|
...etc
```

I am using this function to split the string into a table variable:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString]
    (
        @InputString NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Delim VARCHAR(255)
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS
        RETURN ( SELECT [Value] FROM 
          ( 
            SELECT 
              [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@InputString, [Number],
              CHARINDEX(@Delim, @InputString + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
            FROM (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
              FROM sys.all_objects) AS x
              WHERE Number <= LEN(@InputString)
              AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @InputString, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim
          ) AS y
        );
```

How can this be modified to give the output required above?

Comment: You really should consider keeping the first part of the data in different columns - since it's clearly different data - the first one is a `datetime` value and the second is probably the test identifier - You do not want to save `datetime` as a string and you will probably need to know what test belongs to what identifier.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: @Zohar Yes, I agree.  My intention is to process the data within the variable to store the results properly.  I just need to get the data in the right format first.  The first "row", or first 3 values in the text string, will be treated differently to the actual results.  I will be creating a trigger on the table receiving the records to pick the data up and create a "cleansed" copy of it elsewhere.  This particular server is currently SQL 2014 (so can't use the new functions introduced in 2016!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this tiny inline splitting approach.

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX)='05/10/2018 21:14,#FXAAF00123456,,Cup 1 X Plane,0.00000,OK,Cup 1 Y Plane,0.00000,OK,Cup 1 Z Plane,40.64252,OK,Cup 2 X Plane,77.89434,OK';


;WITH
 a AS (SELECT n=0, i=-1, j=0 UNION ALL SELECT n+1, j, CAST(CHARINDEX(',', @s, j+1) AS INT) FROM a WHERE j > i)
,b AS (SELECT n, SUBSTRING(@s, i+1, IIF(j>0, j, LEN(@s)+1)-i-1) s FROM a WHERE i >= 0)
,c AS (SELECT n,(n-1) % 3 AS Position,(n-1)/3 AS RowIndex,s FROM b) 
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Position=0 THEN s END) AS part1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Position=1 THEN s END) AS part2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Position=2 THEN s END) AS part3
FROM c
GROUP BY RowIndex
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

The result

```
part1               part2           part3
05/10/2018 21:14    #FXAAF00123456  
Cup 1 X Plane       0.00000         OK
Cup 1 Y Plane       0.00000         OK
Cup 1 Z Plane       40.64252        OK
Cup 2 X Plane       77.89434        OK
```

### Hint

You might change your splitter function to the recursive approach above. On the one side you are limited to a string-length of the count in `sys.all_objects` which might be smaller than your input. On the other side your approach has to test each and any position, while the recursive approach *hops* from spot to spot. Should be faster...
This could easily be opened for a *multi-character-delimiter* if needed...

### UPDATE another approach without recursion

...which makes it clumsy to be used in a splitter function (due to `OPTION MAXRECURSION(0)`, which must be placed at the end of the query and cannot live within the function). Try it out:

```
;WITH
 a(Casted) AS (SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT @s AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML))
,b(s,RowIndex,Position) AS 
(
    SELECT x.value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
          ,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) -1) /3 
          ,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) -1) %3 
    FROM a
    CROSS APPLY Casted.nodes(N'/x') X(x)
)
SELECT RowIndex
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Position=0 THEN s END) AS part1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Position=1 THEN s END) AS part2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Position=2 THEN s END) AS part3
FROM b
GROUP BY RowIndex;
```

### Hint:

Using `(SELECT @s AS [*] FOR XML PATH(''))` will make this approach save with forbidden characters...

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately I get a recursion error after 100 - I'm guessing this can be increased somewhere inside SQL settings? I need around 170 per string as there are 56 different readings being returned per string.  Also, can this be tweaked to give me a row number too?

Comment: @AdzzzUK Just add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` as last line to the query...

Comment: @AdzzzUK You can just add it to the resultset. See my update

Comment: Fantastic.  Thank you for your assistance, gives me exactly what I need.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this required a small modification to your `fnSplitString` function. Add a `RowNo` to identify the original sequence of the delimited item

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString]
(
    @InputString NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delim VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
      RETURN ( SELECT [Value] FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT RowNo  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number), 
              [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@InputString, [Number],
          CHARINDEX(@Delim, @InputString + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
        FROM (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
          FROM sys.all_objects) AS x
          WHERE Number <= LEN(@InputString)
          AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @InputString, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim
      ) AS y
    );
```

And with that, you can group every 3 rows as one. Also the `RowNo` can be used to identify the column
The query

```
; with tbl as
(
    select col = '05/10/2018 21:14,#FXAAF00123456,,Cup 1 X Plane,0.00000,OK,Cup 1 Y Plane,0.00000,OK,Cup 1 Z Plane,40.64252,OK,Cup 2 X Plane,77.89434,OK'
)
select  Field1 = MAX(CASE WHEN (RowNo - 1) % 3 = 0 THEN Value END),
        Field2 = MAX(CASE WHEN (RowNo - 1) % 3 = 1 THEN Value END),
        Field3 = MAX(CASE WHEN (RowNo - 1) % 3 = 2 THEN Value END)
from    tbl t
        cross apply dbo.fnSplitString (t.col, ',') 
group by (RowNo - 1) / 3
```

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side. We use the same tricks to *compute* the *three-in-a -row* logic :-)

Comment: I like this idea... can't get the function to work properly though.  Could you update your post with your tweaked fnSplitString function please?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following script after you create the [SQL split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx) given in the reference document.

That split function returns the order of splitted string fragments so that information is used for row data

```
declare @str nvarchar(max) = '05/10/2018 21:14,#FXAAF00123456,,Cup 1 X Plane,0.00000,OK,Cup 1 Y Plane,0.00000,OK,Cup 1 Z Plane,40.64252,OK,Cup 2 X Plane,77.89434,OK'
select
    floor(id / 3)+1 rn,
    case when id % 3 = 1 then val end Field1,
    case when id % 3 = 2 then val end Field2,
    case when id % 3 = 0 then val end Field3
from dbo.Split(@str,',')

select
    rn,
    max(Field1) Field1,
    max(Field2) Field2,
    max(Field3) Field3
from (
select
    floor((id-1) / 3)+1 rn,
    case when id % 3 = 1 then val end Field1,
    case when id % 3 = 2 then val end Field2,
    case when id % 3 = 0 then val end Field3
from dbo.Split(@str,',')
) t
group by rn
```

Comment: The linked splitter function has several serious flaws: 1) Old fashioned *multi-statement* TVF (extremely slow!), 2) It is not save for forbidden characters and 3) it's using a *deep search* (`//root`), which is needlessly slowing down this approach again. There are much better approaches around...

Comment: @Shnugo, I know :) I'm going to modify the UDF with your replacement asap

Comment: It works, gives me what I need for sure.  Speed won't be a huge issue as there's not that many records being inserted per hour so the load will be fairly low.  Interested to see the end result of this approach - I'm learning lots here so thank you all for your insight and input.

Comment: thanks for your nice comments, encouraging to share more :)